# Custom Urls in ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes

When the login page is rendered, I want the Url to be empty. So I added this route

```
routes.MapRoute(
           null, // Route name
           "", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Account", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults                
       );
```

The problem is, when I log in I should be redirected to index which also has an empty Url. So I can't get the page index.

How can I have two empty Urls for two different actions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, and I wouldn't recommend it either.

If you have two different pages, they should have 2 different URLs.

However, you could have something set in your homepage controller which checks whether they are logged in, and redirects to your `LogIn` action:

```
If (check logged in){
   RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account");
}
```

Comment: It should not be done in the home controller but by the authorization features like the `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: @jgauffin Cheers for the advice, I wasn't aware of this. Do you have any links to tutorials etc regarding this?